# Using the roots of polynomial finding the value of sum.

Tags: polynomials

If $a,b$ and $c$ are the roots of $x^{3}+px^{2}+qx+r$, then how can we find the value of $\displaystyle \sum \frac{b^{2}+c^{2}}{bc}$.

Comment: What is the sum over?

Comment: I have a feeling this was supposed to be, find the value of $$\frac {a^2+b^2+c^2} {abc}\, ,$$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are asking for
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{bc}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{ca},\tag{$1$}$$
or perhaps twice this quantity. 
If you bring Expression $(1)$ to a common denominator, you will get
$$\frac{a^2c+b^2c+b^2 a+c^2 a+c^2b+a^2b}{abc}.$$

Note that
$$(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)=a^2c+b^2c+b^2 a+c^2 a+c^2b+a^2b+3abc.$$

Thus 
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{bc}+\frac{c^2+a^2}{ca}=\frac{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-3abc}{abc}.$$
Everything term on the right-hand side is expressible simply in terms of the coefficients.

Comment: That makes sense. +1